# Login and Profile Issues in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a flask Application. I want to the application this way. When User is not logged in or logged out the navigation bar has to contain - HOME, X, Y, LOGIN. When the user logins the navigation bar should change to - HOME, X, Y, PROFILE, LOGOUT. This needs to works for multiple users. But the problem is even if one user logins, it shows HOME, X, Y, PROFILE, LOGOUT even if other users have not logged in and the profile contains the details of the user that has logged in. How can I address this problem?

I am using a class that which contains a variable that is set to true when logged in and returning true when logged in and false when logged.

```
class User:
def __init__(self):
    self.login = self.id = self.name = self.dob = self.age = self.phno = self.add = self.email = self.pwd = self.login = False
def set_user(self, user_id, name, dob, address, phno, email, password):
    self.id = user_id
    self.name = name
    self.dob = dob
    self.age = self.calc_age()
    self.add = address
    self.phno = phno
    self.email = email
    self.pwd = password   
def calc_age(self):
     x = datetime.strptime(self.dob, '%Y-%m-%d')
     today = date.today()
     one_or_zero = ((today.month, today.day) < (x.month, x.day))
     year_difference = today.year - x.year
     y = 1 if one_or_zero else 0
     curr_age = year_difference - y
     return curr_age
def user_in(self):
    self.login = True
def user_out(self):
    self.login = False
def get_user(self):
    return self.login
def check_passowrd(self, pwd):
    return self.pwd == pwd
def get_curr_user_name(self):
    return self.name
curr_user = User()
```

This is the User class. When i want to know if the user is logged in or not i call the get_user method and Also i am creating the object of the class before logining in.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", logged = curr_user.get_user())
```

And this is the code for Nav Bar.

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/query">Queries</a></li>
    <li><a href="/expert">Expert Advice</a></li>
    <li><a href="#foot">Contact</a></li>
    {% if logged == True %}

    <li><a href = "/profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href = "/logout">Logout</a></li>

    {% else %}
    <li><a href = "/login">Login</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: you need to show your code otherwise no one can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using current_user from Flask-Login? this should have the information about spesific user connected.

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
...
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

You can read more here : https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

and you can use current_user object to have more details about the user that is connected currently in the current session

At your model, where your user class is located, you can add

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
class User(UserMixin):
```